# Can't update foreign key reference(navigation property)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern, entity-framework-ctp5

I know that it seems a duplicate entry, but I red all the posts related with my problem and I can't find the solution. I'm stuck with this problem about one week. Maybe I have made some design problem or I don't know. The problem is I can't update a navigation property, I tried several options, everytime i got a different error or a duplicate. Ok, here's the scenario:

> I have an object "List"
>   int ID 
>   string Name 
>   int SendType 
>   Category category //these are navigation property 
>   Product product //these are navigation property

Category and Product don't know about the relation with List. I use POCO classes generated by the CTP5 DbContext Generator Template and I use a repository for every entity. In each repository there's a reference to the dbcontext.

And this is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, List list)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(list);

        List originalList = this._listRepository.Get(id);
        TryUpdateModel(originalList, "List", new string[] { "Name", "SendType"});
        //Here's I tried to update manually like this
        if (list.category.id != originalList.category.id)
        {
           Category category = this._categoryRepository.GetNoTracking(list.category.id);
           originalList.Category = category; 
        }
        if (list.product.id != originalList.product.id)
        {
           Product product = this._productRepository.GetNoTracking(list.product.id);
           originalList.Product = product; 
        }
        this._listRepository.Save(); //Here's I call only the SubmitChanges()
        return RedirectToAction("Index");                               
    }
```

If I try directly I receive the error

> The entity type 'DbEntityEntry' is not part of the model for the current context

because I modify the state of the entity Category or product(they are from another context)

If I submit the changes, without modifying the association, I receive the error

> 'IDCategory' is a reference key and cannot be updated

And so on......Any suggest will be appreciated, I can also modify the viewmodel if I'm wrong.I'm without ideas! Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
    //This is in List Repository
    public override void Save()
    {           
        checkReferencies();
        db.SaveChanges();            
    }

    private void checkReferencies()
    {          
         foreach (var entry in db.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                               .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Added))
         {
             if (ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType()).Name.Equals("List"))
             {
                 /*In this case I tried to update my object directly with the object that comes form the form
                 if (entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<int>("IDList").ToString() != "0" )
                 {
                     db.Entry(entry.Entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                 }    */                 
                 if (((List)entry.Entity).Product != null)
                 {
                     db.Entry(((List)entry.Entity).Product).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                 }
                 if (((List)entry.Entity).Category != null)
                 {
                     db.Entry(((List)entry.Entity).Category).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                 }
             }
             else if (ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType()).Name.Equals("Product") 
                   || ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType()).Name.Equals("Category"))
             {
                 //here I attach the entry that I added
                 db.Category.Attach((Category)db.Entry(entry).Entity.Entity);

             }
         }
    }

    //This is in categoryRepository
    public Category GetNoTracking(int id)
    {            
        return db.Category.AsNoTracking().Single(l => l.IDCategory == id);
    }

    //This is in productRepository
    public Product GetNoTracking(int id)
    {            
        return db.Product.AsNoTracking().Single(l => l.IDProduct == id);
    }

    //This is my DbContext
    namespace BusinessManagerEmail.Models
    {
         using System;
         using System.Data.Entity;

         public partial class DBMailMarketingEntities : DbContext
         {
             public DBMailMarketingEntities()
             : base("name=DBMailMarketingEntities")
             {
             }

             public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
             public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
             public DbSet<Subscription> Subscription { get; set; }
             public DbSet<List> List { get; set; }
             public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
        }
   }
```

This is all the code involved. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you share context among repositories?

Comment: Because it's my first project in MVC and I followed the guidelines of NerdDinner. My next step is add a UnitOfWork that wraps the context. But now I must do as I posted :((obviously is not my will)!

Comment: "because I modify the state of the entity Category or product": Where are you doing this and to what state do you modify? As already indicated by Ladislav, if you have different contexts in "_listRepository" and "_listCategory" then `category` is not attached to the context of _listRepository. Or are some important code fragments missing?

Comment: Yes, they came from different contexts, but when I should attach it? I edit my original post and I'll show you some code that I tried.

Comment: @stuzzo: In my opinion the code snippet of your `ListFormViewModel` and the HTML/Razor snippet are irrelevant for your problem. Remove that from your question and add instead code how `_listRepository` and `_listCategory` (especially those `Get` methods) look like. Perhaps also a piece of your derived DbContext. I think this would be more helpful to answer your question.

Comment: @Slauma: thanks, I'll do now :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `checkReferencies` because:

- `List` in your example is not modified so the first part of the method will not be executed.
- The `Product` cannot be converted to `Category` and attached to `DbSet`. It will throw exception.
- `Category` is already attached in Addes state (which is wrong because it will insert category again). Attaching entity again will throw the exception.

Just attach both `Category` and `Product` to context from `listRepository` before you set them in `List`.

Or better completely rewrite your code and share context among repostiories.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! I try to modify it and I hope to solve it! I'm pretty sure that I'll need your help :P!

Comment: You're totally right! I deleted all my code and I rewrite it with your suggestions! Thanks for your help! Sorry, if I posted a terrible code!